# How to take substring from field between specific chars

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have field which contain a value like:

> F28_TIT245_0_90A_OOC_LCL by AARBITMA(aarbitma@LC13UPE-CIM)

I want to take the name between `'('` and `'@'` which is `"aarbitma"`.

How can I do it?

I'm running on `SQL Server 2008R2`

Comment: what kind of DBMS are you using? the available string functions vary depending on which system you are on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-- there are no checks for wrong input text
-- this is TODO to be done yourself
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @start INT
DECLARE @end INT
SET @text = 'F28_TIT245_0_90A_OOC_LCL by AARBITMA(aarbitma@LC13UPE-CIM)'

SELECT @start = PATINDEX('%(%@%', @text)
SELECT @end = CHARINDEX('@', @text, 0)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@text, @start+1, @end-@start-1)
```

MSDN:

- [PATINDEX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)
- [CHARINDEX()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)
- [SUBSTRING()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)