# Select captured value using only built in T-SQL

Tags: regex, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to extract just the email from

> Violation of UNIQUE
>   KEY constraint 'UQ_Email'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.User'. The duplicate key value is (name.surname@email.com). 
>   The statement has been terminated.

in **DescriptionError** column.

In C# that is a few lines of code but i would like to know is it possible to catch just the **(name.surname@email.com)** part using **T-SQL** *built in functions only*.

What i have tried:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DescriptionError,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%@email.com)%',DescriptionError) - 15,1),35) 
as UserEmail
FROM ErrorLog
order by DateInserted desc
```

This works but i must guess the start/end length.

UPDATE:

Just to be clear, **DescriptionError** column contains all kinds of error logs (as expected for an error log table) and parentheses have different values than email inside.

Comment: So you want to parse the error message in TSQL and extract the email address? Since the address is between two parentheses, why would you have to "guess" the start/end positions?

Comment: Yes. I know it's between parentheses. How would you write REGEX inside PATINDEX to capture it?

Comment: TSQL has no regex support, but your question has already been answered here: [How to take substring from field between specific chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503345/how-to-take-substring-from-field-between-specific-chars)

Comment: @Pondlife i've seen this, as i did my research before I've asked my question, doesn't work for my needs. I know it doesn't have REGEX support that why there is http://www.sqlsharp.com/. But i'm curious how to do it without extensions.

Comment: Please always say what you've tried already and why it didn't work, otherwise people will just suggest the same things again. And since you tagged this question regex, it wasn't clear if you knew that TSQL doesn't support them. Anyway, you've now made your question much broader by asking about "all kinds" of error logs and "different values" that you need to extract. Will the text you need always be inside parentheses? Can there be other parentheses in the message, or are they only around the text you want? Can the text you want ever contain parentheses?

Comment: The only requirement here is to capture email addresses from "junk" text nothing else. Parentheses aren't important at all, notice i didn't mention them in my question, as it can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CHARINDEX. 
Try this:

-- Find the start point

```
DECLARE @Start INT

SELECT @Start = CHARINDEX('(', DescriptionError, 0) 
FROM ErrorLog
```

--Find the end point

```
DECLARE @End INT

SELECT @End = CHARINDEX(')', DescriptionError, 0) 
FROM ErrorLog
```

After reading your update if you really want to use regular expressions I would read this article: 
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/

Answer (score 0):

`Like` patterns are fairly limited, here is one naive way looking for

*A paren > at least one char > @ > domain beginning a-z/0-9 > any more chars > period > tld with 2 a-z > any more chars > paren*

```
create function udfTryGetEmail(@value varchar(1024)) returns varchar(64) as begin
   declare @pos int = 1 + patindex('%(_%@[0-9A-Z]%.[A-Z][A-Z]%)%', @value)
   if @pos = 1
      return ''

   return substring(@value, @pos, charindex(')', @value, @pos) - @pos)
end

select dbo.udfTryGetEmail(DescriptionError) ...
```